# Delete all content but keeping matched

Tags: regex, notepad++

If i have a big text, and i'm needind to keep only matched content, how can i do that?

For example, if I have a text like this:

```
asdas8Isd8m8Td8r
asdia8y8dasd
asd8is88n8gd
asd8t8od8lsdas
as9ea9ad8r1n88r8e87g6765ejasdm8x
```

And use this regex: `[0-9]([a-z])` to group all letters after a number and replace with `\1` i will repace all (number)(letter) to (letter) (And if i want to delete the rest and stay only with the letter matched)?...

Converting this text to

```
ImTr
y
ing
tol
earnregex
```

How can i replace this text with grouped and delete the rest?

And if i want to delete all but no matched?
In this case, converting the text to:

```
8I8m8T8r
8y8d
8i8n8g
8t8o8l
9e9a9r1n8r7g5e8x
```

Can i match all that is not `[0-9]([a-z])`?

Thanks! :D

Comment: You should improve your wording. It's very hard to understand what you actually mean. If you do that we will be able to give more accurate answers.

Comment: Are you sure you want `y` and not `yd` on the second line? Try `(?i-s)[0-9]([a-z])|.` to replace with `(?{1}$1:)`

Comment: I'm trying to delete all text, but keeping matched only...

Comment: Wiktor, thats worked... Tanks! Can you post an answer explaining the code? I will be glad to give you a upvote...

Do you know how to make the same, but keeping ALL matched content?
Like this 

`8I8m8T8r
8y8d
8i8n8g
8t8o8l
9e9a9r1n8r7g5e8x`

Comment: @Emanuel: See my answer, the regex is the same, you just need to replace `$1` with `$0` (the whole match).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
(?i-s)[0-9]([a-z])|.
```

Replace with `(?{1}$1:)`.

To delete all but non-matched, use the `(?{1}$0:)` replacement with the same regex.

**Details**:

- `(?i-s)` - an inline modifier turning on case insensitive mode and turning off the DOTALL mode (`.` does not match a newline)
- `[0-9]([a-z])` - an ASCII digit and any ASCII letter captured into Group 1 (later referred to with `$1` or `\1` backreference from the string replacement pattern)
- `|` - or
- `.` - any char but a line break char.

**Replacement details**

- `(?{1}` - start of the conditional replacement: if Group 1 matched then...

  - `$1` - the contents of Group 1 (or the whole match if `$0` backreference is used)
  - `:` - else... nothing
- `)` - end of the conditional replacement pattern.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Guy! :D

Comment: I have used this,  time and time again to match Multiple criteria.   I cant stress how useful this is.   Than you again Wiktor!