# Regex and multiple matches

Tags: regex

It is standard practice to surround the search criteria in Parenthesis to be able to extract it when using Notepad ++

As an example - when searching for the term  **Setchoice>[0-9]{7,}**   I include the entire line to be able to extract the needed information, so the expression becomes  **(.+Setchoice>([0-9]{7,}).+)**   o

Once isolated, i can preform a search and replace using  \2 variable.

Replace **(.+Setchoice>([0-9]{7,}).+)**  with **\2**

[image]

Example
https://regex101.com/r/NStHQk/1

My question - is there a method of extracting multiple hits ???

thank you for the assistance!

Comment: As you see, it vey easy with Notepad++. Just capture the pattern you need, add a `|.` with *`.` matches newline* option ON and replace with `(?{1}$1:)` or `(?{1}$1\n:)`

Comment: I must be doing something incorrect - all text is removed and no result.  patter is -=Setchoice>[0-9]{7,}|. and replace with (?{1}$1:) or (?{1}$1\n:)

Comment: Yeah, you did not wrap the expected match part with parentheses, your pattern has no group. Should be `(Setchoice>[0-9]{7,})|.`

Comment: Stupid me.!  I should have caught that - Excellent.   I need to review what is going on here as i actually need to results for each line  kept in the line as each of these is record.(simply done by changing the \n to \t) - this will be forever useful! thank you.

Comment: You could upvote at least my ["forever useful" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404941/delete-all-content-but-keeping-matched). As for now, I only got +1.

Comment: Done! very useful - Will need to expand to multiple  groups.