# Exact text (not entire lines) matched by pattern in Notepad++ (npp)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have long lines containing patterns I wish to extract. The pattern I wish to extract is 16 numeric digits, followed by whitespace, followed by 4 digit month-year (MM/YY), followed by whitespace, followed by 3 numeric digits.

I'm able to find the strings of interest with this regex:

```
(([0-9]{15,})\w+)|(\d{1,2}[/]\d{1,2})|(\s[0-9]{3}\s)
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264391/notepad-inverse-regex-replace-all-but-string) about 'Inverse Replace' in NPP with Regex, but the solution there, which is to use `!` or `^` to do a find and replace on everything else doesn't seem to work in this case, perhaps because more than 1 pattern is involved in my search and/or due to the use of `|`.

It was also on the line-level. I also don't want to extract entire lines by marking them then doing line-level operations, because there's lots of extra garbage before and after the target strings on the same lines.

Sample text:

> slfkmsdfklms sdflmds sdlfksdf 0000000000000000 01/01 222 lkm22s2d?f
> slkfdmf02324l/kj slfkmsdfklms sdflmds sdlfksdf 1000000000000000 01/01
> 222 lkm22s2d?f slkfdmf02324l/kj slfkmsdfklms sdflmds sdlfksdf
> 2000000000000000 01/01 222 lkm22s2d?f slkfdmf02324l/kj slfkmsdfklms
> sdflmds sdlfksdf 3000000000000000 01/01 222 lkm22s2d?f
> slkfdmf02324l/kj

Desired result:

> ```
> 0000000000000000 01/01 222
> 1000000000000000 01/01 222
> 2000000000000000 01/01 222
> 3000000000000000 01/01 222
> ```

Alternate (more realistic, less clean) sample text:

> 414720     [SOUTH METRO]   RECORD_NUMBER   SIGNATURE   1142202351790900    02/22   997     NAME J BOONE    [United States] , Doctor , Radio , 01157
> Example     PLATE DATABASE USA, N.A.; loud speaker  0523_US     7.60    VALID
> [T]
> 466245  [SOUTH METRO]   RECORD_NUMBER   RUBY    1662451125354000    09/21   064     DUDE LI     [United States] , Doctor , Columbia , 210AA
> Example     N/A; loud speaker   0523_US     7.60    VALID [T]
> 1891-05-25 01:34  Order #1590359692   (view full information -> txt, csv, short)
> 438857  [SOUTH METRO]   RECORD_NUMBER   SIGNATURE   1388576129333547    02/24   812     LAURA SOMETHING     [United States] , MA , Boston , 0BB130
> Example Phone Email DOB     PLATE DATABASE USA, N.A.; loud speaker
> 0523_US_IP  23.25   VALID [T]
> 1891-05-25 00:08  Order #1590354533   (view full information -> txt, csv, short)
> 414734  [SOUTH METRO]   RECORD_NUMBER   SIGNATURE   1147342081333000    05/23   178     SHEILA TESTEST  [United States] , iPhone , Native , 08020
> Example Phone Email DOB     FIA CARD SERVICES, N.A.; loud speaker
> 0524_US_IP  23.75   VALID [T]
> 1891-05-21 23:23  Order #1590092597   (view full information -> txt, csv, short)
> 414740  [SOUTH METRO]   RECORD_NUMBER   SIGNATURE   0000400204940000    11/22   270     AUSTIN WORDS    [United States] , Doctor , Atlantis , 21157
> Example     PLATE DATABASE USA, N.A.    0521_US     7.60    VALID [T]
> 414709  [V

Comment: You could match it using a group and replace with group 1 `^.*?(\d{16} \d{1,2}/\d{1,2} \d{3}).*` https://regex101.com/r/w8giJm/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks, hmmm for some reason it says that doesn't find any match in the entire document. Let me try using more realistic sample data in case that helps clarify the problem. Just 1 moment.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/uvWUO1/1

Comment: This question has NOT already been answered, despite the false flag to that effect!! That only works on the line level!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, if you try that with the updated sample text, it doesn't work

Comment: Try it like this, match `(\d{16}\h+\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}\h+\d{3})|\D*(?:\d(?!\d{15})\D*)*` and replace with `(?{1}$1\n:` See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UHGCO5/1) and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQDKb.png)

Comment: @Thefourthbird That worked!!

Comment: @Hack-R Awesome :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There is a different example added to the question. Can I post it as an answer?

Comment: Change dupe to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404941/delete-all-content-but-keeping-matched/45405085#45405085. It is the same technique.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Agreed ++